Date range picker nextui issue
Am trying to get start and end date from user using DateRangePicker from nextui and everything is working on good way but when i try to click on separator on date field or try to click at any empty space at field it gives an error
error:
Failed to execute 'createTreeWalker' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createTreeWalker' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
here are my code:
import { DateRangePicker } from "@nextui-org/react";
const {
control,
handleSubmit,
setValue,
getValues,
formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
defaultValues: {
title: "",
dateRange: "",
category: "",
location: "",
budget: "",
currency: "",
importance: "",
tags: [],
desc: "",
},
});
async function addFrond(reqBody) {
const start_date = ${reqBody.dateRange.start.day}/${reqBody.dateRange.start.month}/${reqBody.dateRange.start.year};
const end_date = ${reqBody.dateRange.end.day}/${reqBody.dateRange.end.month}/${reqBody.end.year};
try {
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    "",
    {
      title: reqBody.title,
      start_date,
      end_date,
      category: reqBody.category,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );
  console.log(data);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

}
<Controller
name="dateRange"
control={control}
rules={{
required: "Date range is required",
}}
render={({ field }) => (
        <DateRangePicker
          {...field}
          label="Start Date - End Date"
          variant="bordered"
          labelPlacement="outside"
          visibleMonths={2}
          selectorIcon={
            <Image src={calendar} className="w-[18px] h-[18px]" />
          }
          isInvalid={errors.dateRange?.message ? true : false}
          errorMessage={errors.dateRange?.message}
          classNames={{
            base: "mt-0 h-[68px]",
            label: "text-textColor font-normal text-sm",
            inputWrapper:
              "border-[0.86px] p-0 border-solid border-[#E5E4EB] rounded-[8px] min-h-[42px] flex-row-reverse",
            innerWrapper: "px-[18px]",
            segment: "uppercase date-picker-frond text-sm font-normal",
            selectorButton:
              "order-first min-w-[18px] max-h-[18px] h-[18px] me-1",
            separator: "mx-0 date-picker-frond text-sm font-normal",
          }}
        />
      )}
    />

Any help please and thanks

What are NextJS, NextUI & NodeJS version ? Are you using app or pages router ?

am using react js not next js, nextui version 2.3.1, and am using app router
